# Python protobuf 3.20.1 is missing Any, Empty, and other types

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I just upgraded protobuf from 3.17.3 to 3.20.1 (macos, python 3.9), and my code started complaining that there is no

```
from google.protobuf.empty_pb2 import Empty
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp
```

I checked the package folder under `./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/` and indeed there is no `Empty` type there.

Ok, I found Timestamp in `internal/well_known_types.py`.
Why internal? It does not make sense.

Also cannot find `StringValue` and other wrapper types.

Is it a known bug, or I'm missing something?
How does someone construct `Empty` or `StringValue` objects now?

Comment: "My code worked before I upgraded the version of a third-party library" is usually a tech support question. Have you tried the [issue tracker](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues)?

Comment: Yes, it's the next step if I am sure it's indeed an issue.

Comment: How did you install protobuf 3.20.1? If I `pip install protobuf`, I get version 3.20.1, and `from google.protobuf.empty_pb2 import Empty` works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found out my problem. Everything worked in the first place, but IDE had been complaining about missing types until I installed the `types-protobuf` package.